# How to pass props from child component to parent component to another child component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-component

I'm currently creating a search bar where `App` is the parent and  `Header`, `Home` are the children. I'm trying to pass the input from `Header` to `Home` via `App` but it seems that when I try to load in `{this.state.searchValue}` it does nothing.

I'm lost of where I am wrong in my code. I'm also using `Route` to route the props from `Header` to `Home`.

Here is my code:

**Header.js (Child 1)**

```
class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search: "",
    };
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ search: event.target.value });
  };

  submitSearch = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.search);
    this.props.passSearchData(this.state.search);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <form className="form-inline">
                <input
                  className="form-control mr-sm-2"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Search"
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
                <button
                  className="btn btn-danger"
                  type="submit"
                  onClick={this.submitSearch}
                >
                  Search
                </button>
              </form>
        </nav>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

**App.js (Parent)**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      searchValue: "",
    };
  }

  handleSearchData = (search) => {
    this.setState({ searchValue: search });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getItems();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Header passSearchData={this.handleSearchData} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={(props) => (
              <Home {...props} searchValue={this.state.searchValue} />
            )}
          />
        </Router>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Home.js**

```
class Catalog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }
render() {
return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.searchValue}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using react context better for this problem, because passing state between routes quite painful

First u declare your own Provider to act as intermediary between components.
The context will save all the application state. and to consume at your components, simply use `useContext` and pass the Context u want to use, at this useCase, i call it `AppContext`. by using the same context, your components get the same state and trigger update immediately

The solution i provide is using functional component. If u are using class Component, just simply create a functional component, then pass the context to the class component

```js
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'

const AppContext = React.createContext({})

const AppProvider = props => {
  const [currentState, setCurrentState] = useState(null)
  
  const handleState = value => {
    setCurrentState(value)
  }
  
  const contextValue = { handleState, currentState }
  
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}

const Child1 = props => {
  const { handleState } = useContext(AppContext)
  
  const handleClick = e => {
    handleState(e.target.values)
  }
  
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Change State</button>
  )
}

const Child2 = props => {
  const { currentState } = useContext(AppContext)
  
  return (
    <h1>{currentState}</h1>
  )
}

const Parent = props => {
  
  return (
    <Router>
      <AppProvider>
        <Route component={Child1} />
        <Route component={Child2} />
      </AppProvider>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, your answer sounds interesting. I'll try using context.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw i just edit some wrong code, change from `useContext` to `React.createContext` at root